How to setup Canon 2900B printer in Ubuntu 24.04 step by step?
Please give a step by step guide for a rookie like me to setup canon 2900b printer on ubuntu 24.04. I tried to install drivers from canon support US, that didn't work. I also tried:

How to install Canon LBP2900 / 2900B printer on Ubuntu but that didn't work for me either.
I couldn't understand much from this discussion also-
Printing problem , Canon LBP2900

Details:

BRAND-CANON
Model-2900B
Connection- Via USB

So please give a step by step guide instead of discussion links if possible. It would help a lot of people like me to switch to linux.
Thank You.
i went to How to install Canon LBP2900 / 2900B printer on Ubuntu

download the setup.sh file

edited with text editor -
edited directory in the file according to my location of /home/mahiraj/desktop/ (as given in properties section), then replaced the github links part with corrected link part given in ask ubuntu link under>script link> github>issues>replace download links.
https://github.com/hieplpvip/ubuntu_canon_printer/issues/15

saved the changes and went to terminal to type the command for executable and run-
chmod +x canon_lbp_setup.sh
./canon_lbp_setup.sh


pressed 1 for install

4 for 2900

1 via usb then turned on my printer's back switch


installation started but at the end the following packages were not found for installation as given in the image.
://i.sstatic.net/Jf6cf9z2.jpg

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

edited please check

@JIGARPATEL Can you try installing the packages one by one? sudo apt install libatk1.0-0 and sudo apt install libatk1.0-0:i386, etc.

@graham That post does not solve the issue due to missing dependencies

First, add the i386 architecture.
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update

Now install libpango with
sudo apt install libpango-1.0-0:i386

This package was renamed from libpango1.0-0:i386 to libpango-1.0-0:i386.
Now, download and run the installer (my fork, with fixed driver download links)
git clone https://github.com/archisman-panigrahi/ubuntu_canon_printer.git
cd ubuntu_canon_printer
chmod +x canon_lbp_setup.sh
./canon_lbp_setup.sh

Before run canon_lbp_setup.sh script, change libpango1.0-0 to libpango-1.0-0
If there are other missing packages, install them one by one, and run the installer again.
You may have to run the following, so that the computer finds the printer after restart.
sudo systemctl enable ccpd.service
sudo systemctl restart ccpd.service

To monitor the printer status, create a desktop file
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications && echo -e '[Desktop Entry]\nVersion=1.0\nName=Canon LBP6020\nComment=Canon CAPT Printer Status Monitor\nExec=captstatusui -P LBP6020\nTerminal=false\nType=Application\nIcon=/usr/share/icons/Yaru/256x256/devices/printer.png' > ~/.local/share/applications/canon-lbp6020.desktop && chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/canon-lbp6020.desktop

Now, copy-paste it to autostart directory so that the printer is added automatically after restart.
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart && cp ~/.local/share/applications/canon-lbp6020.desktop ~/.config/autostart/canon-lbp6020.desktop


Source: https://github.com/hieplpvip/ubuntu_canon_printer/issues/24

the best method i found was in the comment/info of this youtube video with the given g drive link for the script and it works perfectly fine .....----     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4W9Hv1ZsEVU          Step1- add 32bit sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386    Step 2 download script and place in desktop, edit the directory location inside script    Step3 open terminal in desktop give permissions to script      chmod u+r+x canon_lbp_setup.sh      Step4 run script in terminal and follow it  ./canon_lbp_setup.sh      Step5 right click on the new printer icon and click on allow launching. PERFECT

@JIGARPATEL My answer does the same
